# INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

I'm not sure how to achieve something like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnJobQueueBEFORE() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    DECLARE
        shadowname varchar := TG_TABLE_NAME || 'shadow';
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO shadowname VALUES(OLD.*);
        RETURN OLD;
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I.e. inserting values into a table with a dynamically generated name.
Executing the code above yields:

```
ERROR:  relation "shadowname" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO shadowname VALUES(OLD.*)
```

It seems to suggest variables are not expanded/allowed as table names. I've found no reference to this in the Postgres manual.

I've already experimented with `EXECUTE` like so:

```
  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(shadowname) || ' VALUES ' || OLD.*;
```

But no luck:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: INSERT INTO personenshadow VALUES (1,sven,,,)
```

The `RECORD` type seems to be lost: `OLD.*` seems to be converted to a string and get's reparsed, leading to all sorts of type problems (e.g. `NULL` values).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

#### Modern PostgreSQL

[`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) has a built-in way to escape identifiers. Simpler than before:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo_before()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I.%I SELECT $1.*'
                , TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME || 'shadow')
   USING OLD;

   RETURN OLD;
END
$func$;
```

Works with a [`VALUES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html) expression as well.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8221af89a32edc91d82a7fadfe6150a9)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ff78f/1)</sub>

#### Major points

- Use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) or [`quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to quote identifiers (automatically and only where necessary), thereby defending against [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) and simple syntax violations.
  This is *necessary*, even with your own table names!
- Schema-qualify the table name. Depending on the current [`search_path` setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860) a bare table name might otherwise resolve to another table of the same name in a different schema.
- Use **`EXECUTE`** for dynamic DDL statements.
- Pass *values* safely with the **`USING`** clause.
- Consult the fine manual on [Executing Dynamic Commands in plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).
- Note that`RETURN OLD;` in the trigger function is required for a trigger **`BEFORE DELETE`**. [Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html)

You get the **error message** in your almost successful version because `OLD` is **not visible** inside `EXECUTE`. And if you want to concatenate individual values of the decomposed row like you tried, you have to prepare the text representation of every single column with `quote_literal()` to guarantee valid syntax. You would also have to *know* column names beforehand to handle them or query the system catalogs - which stands against your idea of having a simple, dynamic trigger function ...

My solution avoids all these complications. Also simplified a bit.

#### PostgreSQL 9.0 or earlier

`format()` is not available, yet, so:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo_before()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_SCHEMA)
                    || '.' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME || 'shadow')
                    || ' SELECT $1.*'
    USING OLD;

    RETURN OLD;
END
$func$;
```

Related:

- [How to dynamically use TG_TABLE_NAME in PostgreSQL 8.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519044/how-to-dynamically-use-tg-table-name-in-postgresql-8-2/7617533#7617533)

Comment: Works like a charm. I guess i'll have some further reading to do :) There's a typo in your [manual link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), though. Can't correct it, becaus stackoverflow thinks one character edits are too minor :/

Comment: @Johan: Ah, didn't know that. So, i'll have to keep asking such great questions *g*!

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter : my schema and  table name are in upper case. So while executing this query i get error due to misplaced double-quotes `EXECUTE format ('INSERT INTO %I SELECT $1.*', 'SCHEMA_NAME' || '.' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '_SHADOW') USING (row)`. Error is: `ERROR:  relation "SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME" does not exist`

Comment: @Siddharth: The schema is contained in a separate variable `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA`. It seems like you concatenated both *before* escaping properly. Consider: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860. If the problem is still unclear, start a new question. You can always reference this answer for context and/or add a comment her linking to the related question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Hi there. all the things I get it except `USING  OLD;`. You said: "Pass values safely with the USING clause." can you further elaborate?  I checked insert clause, there is no `USING`

Comment: @Jian: `USING` is part of the `EXECUTE` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled upon this because I was searching for a dynamic `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger. As a thank you for the question and answers I'll post my solution for Postgres 9.3.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_deleted_instead_of_delete()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I set deleted = now() WHERE id = $1.id', TG_TABLE_NAME)
    USING OLD;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Could you explain, what new concept or idea your solution is bringing to the table?

Comment: Reading my post again, I see that I wasn't clear about the context of it.

My post is for the one that is searching for a dynamically on delete trigger function. I was searching for this when Google showed this question as a hit.

Comment: Originally i wanted to post it as a comment under the answer, but the code highlighting didn't work

Comment: Important to note that this is only meant for `INSTEAD OF DELETE` triggers. I took the liberty to clarify accordingly.