# How to create SQL function with parameter?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have an SQL function:

```
-- Function: insert_into_wgs()

-- DROP FUNCTION insert_into_wgs();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_into_wgs()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO parcels (num,vid,support_num,name_dispatcher,cadastr,the_geom,status_id)  
SELECT num,vid,support_num,name_dispatcher,cadastr,ST_TRANSFORM(the_geom,4326),status_id
FROM parcels_temp
WHERE num NOT IN (SELECT num FROM parcels)AND deleted='no';
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION insert_into_wgs() OWNER TO postgres;
```

You see that it works only for `parcels`, `parcels_temp` tables. How can I create function with parameters `insert_into_wgs(table, table_temp);`?

Comment: Have you already tried `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_into_wgs(table, table_temp)`?

Comment: Yeah, its says that table is note type.

Comment: I dont know how this functions calls so cant ask my question to google(

Comment: https://www.google.cz/?q=stored+function+postgresql

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL if you want to parameterize identifiers. And use `EXECUTE` in plpgsql, [similar to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100).

Comment: I read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100 and cant understand what its mean. How its use dynamic table name?

Comment: Can you give me very vety simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you have to use **dynamic SQL** if you want to parametrize identifiers. And use [`EXECUTE` in plpgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

In the base query better use `NOT EXISTS` instead of col `NOT IN (<subquery>)`.

Now, if *only* the table names change and the columns stay the same, this simple demo would do the job:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_into_tbl(_tbl text, _tbl_tmp text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format($x$
INSERT INTO %I (...)  -- enter columns
SELECT ...            -- enter columns
FROM %I t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   %1$I p     -- reuse first table name
    WHERE  p.num = t.num
    )
AND   deleted = 'no'$x$, _tbl, _tbl_tmp);

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Check out [`format()` in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html).
There are quite a few related answers on SO. [Try this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2b%5Bdynamic-sql%5D%20%2b%5Bplpgsql%5D%20%2bexecute&submit=search).

Comment: In Postgres i dont get errors. Now try call this function in java)

Comment: @KliverMax: Note I fixed the `WHERE` condition to match your example.

Comment: I get a error : `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "parcels" does not exist`.  In java i call function :  `java.sql.CallableStatement proc =  ce_proc.prepareCall("{call insert_into_wgs("+t_name+","+t_temp+")}")`

Comment: @KliverMax: My bad, I forgot to parametrize the second occurrence of the table name.

Comment: @KliverMax: Well, then `column "parcels"` probably `does not exist`. You may have missed my assertion: `if only the table names change and the columns stay the same`. You can build column names into the query, too. You need to query `pg_catalog.pg_attribute` or the information_schema for this. I posted a couple of related answers in the past. But no more time now.

Comment: Yeah im really stupid. Foggot about columns( But thanx for help.