# Call function from concatenated strings

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have two strings:

- 'UPP'
- 'ER'

And the value, 'a' for example.

I need to call the function `UPPER` (synthesized from the two strings) and pass the value as parameter.
How can I do this?

In reality, I need to concat the function **`crosstab()`** with the counter of columns ...

Comment: Seriously?  You can make this a bit harder if you use ascii values...

Comment: @PinnyM: Is just one example, solving it, I solve a big problem.

Comment: I don't really understand the question but Dynamic SQL?

Comment: @E.T.: Yes, I need call the function crosstabN dynamically according with the number of columns necessary. Solving the above case, I solve my problem.

Comment: To execute this as dynamic SQL you also need to define the *return type* of the function.

Answer (score 3):

A stub for a function utilizing dynamic SQL could look like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_exec(text, text, text, OUT result text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || $1  || $2 || '($1)'  -- last ($1) not a reference to func param
    INTO   result
    USING  $3;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_exec('up', 'per', 'a')
```

Don't get confused, `$1` has its own scope inside `EXECUTE` and refers to the parameter passed in by the `USING` clause, not to the outer function parameter.

More background in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7915100/939860) or in the chapter [Executing Dynamic Commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in the manual.

#### WARNING

The above naive use of dynamic SQL invites **SQL injection**!

Read the advice under [this related question on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34002/3684) and and the chapter ["Writing `SECURITY DEFINER` Functions Safely"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY) in the manual.

There is a smart way to **avoid SQLi** in this special case:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_exec(func1 text, func2 text, param text
                                , OUT result text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   funcname text := (func1 || func2)::regproc;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || funcname || '($1)::text'
   INTO   result
   USING  param;
END
$func$;
```

The cast to the [object identifier type `regproc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) effectively weeds out all attempts to inject anything but a valid function name via `$1` and `$2`. The `USING` clause already neutralizes attempts to inject code via `$3` (`param`).

Also:

- Use parameter names to make it less confusing.
- Omit the `RETURNING` clause from the function definition, since the `OUT` parameter takes care of it.
- Cast the result of the function to `text` since we don't know the actual return type of the function and every data type in Postgres can be cast to `text`.
  The function still need to accept a single `IN` parameter of type `text` or you get an exception.