# truncate function doesnt work in postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, ddl, postgresql-8.4

I have created the following function to truncate bunch of tables starting with "irm_gtresult". There are no syntax errors in my function, but the function doesn't truncate the tables when I run it. What could be wrong here?

My Postgres db version is 8.4.

```
create or replace function br()
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
row text;
BEGIN
 FOR row IN
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name ILIKE 'irm_gtresult%'
LOOP
EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || row;
END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Call:

```
select br();
```

Comment: You are querying all the tables that start with `irm_gtresult`, not `irm`. Is that intentional?

Comment: I pasted the code it is not a sceenshot, I judge upon size of the directory where the database resides. Yes, I want intentionally truncate those table that start with 'irm_gtresult'. In fact the standalone select table_name from information_schema.tables where  table_name ILIKE  'irm_gtresult%'   returns the list of tables exactly that I want to truncate.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Your version of Postgres? How exactly do you run it? Connected to the right database? Do you get any messages? If 'irm_gtresult%' is the pattern you want, please fix the text of your question.

Comment: Use row. table_name in your TRUNCATE statement, not just row.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: `row` isn't actually a row in his code. That's just a very unfortunate variable name.

Comment: but the 'row' actually denotes the table name, look when I execute the following statement, I recieve the list of tables that I need to truncate:

    53=# select table_name from information_schema.tables where  table_name ILIKE  'irm_gtresult%'
53-# ;
       table_name
-------------------------
 irm_gtresult_1393803000
 irm_gtresult_1393552800

Comment: How do you know it's "not working"? How do you check that the tables are empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is valid. I tested and it works for me in Postgres 9.4.
Using the [outdated and unsupported version 8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) (like you added) *may* be the problem. The version is just too old, consider upgrading to a current version.

However, I have a couple of suggestions:

- Don't use key word `row` as variable name.
- You don't need to loop, you can [`TRUNCATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-truncate.html) all tables in a single command. Faster, shorter.
- You may need to add `CASCADE` if there are dependencies. Be aware of the effect.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION br()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
      SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE '
          || string_agg(format('%I.%I', schemaname, tablename), ',')
          || ' CASCADE'
      FROM   pg_tables t
      WHERE  tablename ILIKE 'irm_gtresult%'
      AND    schemaname = 'public'
      -- AND tableowner = 'postgres'  -- optionaly restrict to one user
      );
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT br();
```

I am using the view [`pg_tables`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/view-pg-tables.html) from the system catalog. You can as well use [`information_schema.tables`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/infoschema-tables.html) like you did. Note the subtle differences:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

Related answers with more explanation:

- [Can I truncate tables dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804831/can-i-truncate-tables-dynamically/16804899#16804899)
- [Truncating all tables in a Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829158/truncating-all-tables-in-a-postgres-database/12082038#12082038)

Comment: Another potential reason: d88 is not using auto commit and simply not committing

Comment: Guys, thank you very much for your help! Adding 'CASCADE' into the statement solved the issue.And sorry for my annoying style of writing the post, next time I will bear in mind the rules;)

Answer (score 0):

To truncate in postgres you just have to use the TRUNC() function.

Example:

```
SELECT TRUNC(price, 0) AS truncated_price
FROM product;
```