# How to use dynamic column names in an UPDATE or SELECT statement in a function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameter-passing, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

In PostgreSQL 9.1, PL/pgSQL, given a query:

```
select fk_list.relname from ...
```

where `relname` is of type `name` (e.g., "table_name").

How do you get the appropriate value for "relname" that can be used directly in an `UPDATE` statement as:

```
Update <relname> set ...
```

within the PL/pgSQL script?

Using `quote_ident(r.relname)` as:

```
Update quote_ident(r.relname) Set ...
```

fails with:

> syntax error at or near "("
>      LINE 55:   UPDATE quote_ident(r.relname) ....

The complete code I am working with:

```
CREATE FUNCTION merge_children_of_icd9 (ocicd9 text, 
                      ocdesc text, ncicd9 text, ncdesc text)
RETURNS void AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  r RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN
    WITH fk_actions ( code, action ) AS (
      VALUES ('a', 'error'), 
             ('r', 'restrict'), 
             ('c', 'cascade'),
             ('n', 'set null'),
             ('d', 'set default')
    ), fk_list AS (
      SELECT pg_constraint.oid AS fkoid, conrelid, confrelid::regclass AS parentid,
             conname, relname, nspname,
             fk_actions_update.action AS update_action,
             fk_actions_delete.action AS delete_action,
             conkey AS key_cols
      FROM pg_constraint
      JOIN pg_class ON conrelid = pg_class.oid
      JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid
      JOIN fk_actions AS fk_actions_update ON confupdtype = fk_actions_update.code
      JOIN fk_actions AS fk_actions_delete ON confdeltype = fk_actions_delete.code
      WHERE contype = 'f'
    ), fk_attributes AS (
      SELECT fkoid, conrelid, attname, attnum
      FROM fk_list
      JOIN pg_attribute ON conrelid = attrelid AND attnum = ANY(key_cols)
      ORDER BY fkoid, attnum
    ), fk_cols_list AS (
      SELECT fkoid, array_agg(attname) AS cols_list
      FROM fk_attributes
      GROUP BY fkoid
    )
    SELECT fk_list.fkoid, fk_list.conrelid, fk_list.parentid, fk_list.conname, 
           fk_list.relname, fk_cols_list.cols_list
    FROM fk_list
    JOIN fk_cols_list USING (fkoid)
    WHERE parentid = 'icd9'::regclass
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'now in loop. relname is %', quote_ident(r.relname);
    RAISE NOTICE 'cols_list[1] is %', quote_ident(r.cols_list[1]);
    RAISE NOTICE 'cols_list[2] is %', quote_ident(r.cols_list[2]);
    RAISE NOTICE 'now doing update';

    UPDATE quote_ident(r.relname) SET r.cols_list[1] = ncicd9, r.cols_list[2] = ncdesc
    WHERE r.cols_list[1] = ocicd9 AND r.cols_list[2] = ocdesc;

    RAISE NOTICE 'finished update'; 
  END LOOP;     
  RETURN;
END $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;   

-- select merge_children_of_icd9('', 'aodm type 2', '', 'aodm, type 2');
```

I'm sure this kind of thing is done often, but I can't seem to find anything like it using PostgreSQL. Is there a better way?

Comment: Show us the complete code for your function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name O.k. Please see Edit of question. Any critique is more then welcome :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an `UPDATE` statement in PL/pgSQL, the table name has to be given as a literal. If you want to dynamically set the table name and the columns, you should use the [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) command and paste the query string together:

```
EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || quote_ident(r.relname) ||
       ' SET ' || quote_ident(r.cols_list[1]) || ' = $1, ' || 
                  quote_ident(r.cols_list[2]) || ' = $2' ||
       ' WHERE ' || quote_ident(r.cols_list[1]) || ' = $3 AND ' ||
                    quote_ident(r.cols_list[2]) || ' = $4'
USING ncicd9, ncdesc, ocicd9, ocdesc;
```

The `USING` clause can only be used for substituting data values, as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

You need dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` like @Patrick already provided.
However, both your function and the `EXECUTE` part can be **much simpler**. In particular, use [**`format()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to concatenate longer query strings safely (available since pg 9.1):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_children_of_icd9 (_ocicd9 text, _ocdesc text
                                                 , _ncicd9 text, _ncdesc text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
BEGIN
   FOR _sql IN
      SELECT format('UPDATE %3$s SET %1$I = $3   , %2$I = $4
                     WHERE           %1$I = $1 AND %2$I = $2'
                   , x.cols[1], x.cols[2], x.conrelid::regclass::text)
      FROM  (
         SELECT c.conrelid, array_agg(a.attname ORDER BY a.attnum) AS cols
         FROM   pg_constraint c
         JOIN   pg_attribute  a ON a.attrelid = c.conrelid
                               AND a.attnum = ANY(c.conkey)
         WHERE  c.confrelid = 'icd9'::regclass
         AND    c.contype = 'f'
         GROUP  BY c.oid, c.conrelid
         ORDER  BY c.oid
         ) x
   LOOP
   -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;  -- debug?
      EXECUTE _sql
      USING   _ocicd9, _ocdesc, _ncicd9, _ncdesc;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

The function errors out if the FK constraint does not span at least two columns or if the data type of the columns is not compatible with `text`. May or may not be as intended.

Details on how to pass identifiers safely and execute dynamic SQL:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)