# How to update column based on column name in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, massivejs

I've narrowed it down to two possibilities - DynamicSQL and using a case statement.

However, I've failed with both of these.

I simply don't understand dynamicSQL, and how I would use it in my case.

This is my attempt using case statements; one of many failed variations.

```
SELECT column_name,
CASE WHEN column_name = 'address' THEN (**update statement gives syntax error within here**)
END
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'employees';
```

**As an overview, I'm using Axios to talk to my Node server, which is making calls to my Heroku database using Massivejs.**

Maybe this isn't the way to go - so here's my main problem:

I've ran into troubles because the values I'm planning on using as column names are sent to my server as strings. The exact call that I've been trying to use is

```
update employees
set $1 = $2
where employee_id = $3;
```

Once again, I'm passing into those using massive.

I get the error back `{ error: syntax error at or near "'address'"}` because my incoming values are strings. My thought process was that the above statement would allow me to use variables because `'address'` is encapsulated by quotes.

But alas, my thought process has failed me.

This seems to be close to answering my question, but I can't seem to figure out what to do in my case if using dynamic SQL.

[How to use dynamic column names in an UPDATE or SELECT statement in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743475/how-to-use-dynamic-column-names-in-an-update-or-select-statement-in-a-function)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you a way to do this by using a function.
First we create the employees table :

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
column1 TEXT,
column2 TEXT
);
```

Next, we create a function that requires three parameters:

`columnName` - the name of the column that needs to be updated

`columnValue` - the new value to which the column needs to be updated

`employeeId` - the id of the employee that will be updated

By using the format function we generate the update query as a string and use the EXECUTE command to execute the query.

Here is the code of the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_columns_on_employee(columnName TEXT, columnValue TEXT, employeeId BIGINT)
  RETURNS VOID AS
  $$
  DECLARE update_statement TEXT := format('UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET %s = ''%s'' WHERE id = %L',columnName, columnValue, employeeId);
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE update_statement;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now, lets insert some data into the employees table

```
  INSERT INTO employees(column1, column2) VALUES ('column1_start_value','column2_start_value');
```

So now we currently have an employee with an `id` value of 1 who has 'column1_start_value' value for the `column1`, and 'column2_start_value' value for `column2`.

If we want to update the value of `column2` from 'column2_start_value' to 'column2_new_value' all we have to do is execute the following call

```
SELECT * FROM update_columns_on_employee('column2','column2_new_value',1);
```