# Execute a SELECT with dynamic ORDER BY expression inside a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression, dynamic-sql, stored-functions

I'm trying to EXECUTE some SELECTs to use inside a function, my code is something like this:

```
DECLARE
result_one record;

BEGIN 
    EXECUTE 'WITH Q1 AS 
        (
            SELECT id
            FROM table_two
            INNER JOINs, WHERE, etc, ORDER BY... DESC
        )

        SELECT Q1.id
        FROM Q1 
        WHERE, ORDER BY...DESC';

RETURN final_result;
END;
```

I know how to do it in MySQL, but in PostgreSQL I'm failing. What should I change or how should I do it?

Comment: It's not obvious (to me at least) why you are using `EXECUTE`, or what results you expect from this query. There's no reason for the above code to even be in plpgsql - you could just use a SQL function

Comment: I know, the selects are examples, I need to know how to use the execute in this case. Those select has dynamic parameters, and some people will edit the parameters through CLI, long story.

Comment: Then you will need to give a more accurate example if you want people to figure out what your problem is. That code just isn't returning any results and I can't see why you would expect it to. You have read the relevant part of the manuals (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) haven't you?

Comment: Note that *functions* are distinct from *procedures*, so "stored procedure"  (SP) is a misleading term when referring to a function. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/194811/3684

Answer (score 1):

For a function to be able to return multiple rows it has to be declared as `returns table()` (or `returns setof`)

And to actually return a result from within a PL/pgSQL function you need to use `return query` (as [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.3.4))

To build dynamic SQL in Postgres it is highly recommended to use the `format()` function to properly deal with identifiers (and to make the source easier to read).

So you need something like:

```
create or replace function get_data(p_sort_column text)
  returns table (id integer)
as
$$
begin
  return query execute 
    format(
     'with q1 as (
           select id
           from table_two
             join table_three on ...
         )
         select q1.id
         from q1
         order by %I desc', p_sort_column);
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Note that the `order by` inside the CTE is pretty much useless if you are sorting the final query unless you use a `LIMIT` or `distinct on ()` inside the query.

---

You can make your life even easier if you use another level of dollar quoting for the dynamic SQL:

```
create or replace function get_data(p_sort_column text)
  returns table (id integer)
as
$$
begin
  return query execute 
    format(
     $query$ 
       with q1 as (
           select id
           from table_two
             join table_three on ...
         )
         select q1.id
         from q1
         order by %I desc
     $query$, p_sort_column);
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

[What a_horse said.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53265548/939860) And:

- [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)

**Plus**, to pick a column for `ORDER BY` dynamically, you have to add that column to the `SELECT` list of your CTE, which leads to complications if the column can be duplicated (like with passing 'id') ...

Better yet, **remove the CTE entirely**. There is nothing in your question to warrant its use anyway. (Only use CTEs when *needed* in Postgres, they are typically slower than equivalent subqueries or simple queries.)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data(p_sort_column text)
  RETURNS TABLE (id integer) AS
$func$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
   $q$ 
   SELECT t2.id  -- assuming you meant t2?
   FROM   table_two   t2
   JOIN   table_three t3 on ...
   ORDER  BY t2.%I DESC NULL LAST  -- see below!
   $q$, $1);
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I appended `NULLS LAST` - you'll probably want that, too:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

If `p_sort_column` is from the same table all the time, hard-code that table name / alias in the `ORDER BY` clause. Else, pass the table name / alias *separately* and auto-quote them separately to be safe:

- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)

I suggest to table-qualify all column names in a bigger query with multiple joins (`t2.id` not just `id`). Avoids various kinds of surprising results / confusion / abuse.

And you may want to schema-qualify your table names (`myschema.table_two`) to avoid similar troubles when calling the function with a different `search_path`:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)