# Function to add new column dynamically with ALTER TABLE

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, ddl

I'm trying to add a field to a table dynamically. I created a function and pass field name and datatype that I would like to create:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE function "trustedforms2"."parametertest"("_pname" varchar)
 AS $BODY$BEGIN
    -- Routine body goes here...
ALTER TABLE byoung.formdata ADD COLUMN _pname varchar(255); 

END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

This always creates a field named "_pname" regardless of the value I pass.   How do I get the function to evaluate the variable by value and not as a literal? I tried `"_pname"`, `'_pname'`, `%1 %_pname` and either get an error or a field called "_pname".

Comment: You need [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using dynamic SQL, be sure to quote / escape user input that's converted to code properly to **avoid attack vectors for SQL injection**! Basics:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49718/3684)
- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Also, Postgres identifiers only preserve capitalization when double-quoted:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Basic safe version of your routine:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE trustedforms2.parametertest(_pname text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE byoung.formdata ADD COLUMN %I varchar(255)', _pname); 
END
$proc$;
```

Capitalization is preserved this way. To force lower-case names, use `lower(_pname)` instead. (You still want to double-quote the identifier properly!)

You may or may not want to check first whether the table exists, and whether the column doesn't. The simple form raises an exception if those assumptions don't hold.

You can use a [`PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xproc.html) for this like you chose in your answer, but remember to execute it with [`CALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html):

```
CALL trustedforms2.parametertest('my_columns_name');
```

I would probably stick to a (more common) function.

And the type `varchar(255)`typically is a misunderstanding in Postgres:

- [Should I add an arbitrary length limit to VARCHAR columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21496/3684)

Answer (score 0):

oK,  solved

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "trustedforms2"."parametertest"("_pname" varchar)
 AS $BODY$BEGIN
EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE byoung.formdata ADD COLUMN ' || _pname || ' varchar(255)' ; 

END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: Beware of functions with an attack path for SQL injection!