# How to call a created function in PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I created a dynamic SQL function for the first time and wondering what is the correct way to call the function? Here's the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION functions.search_function(_columns text)
    RETURNS TABLE(student text,
    student_id text,
    professor_name text,
    subject text,
    subject_time text,
    room_number text,
    building text) 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _columns text := 'student_id::text, subject_timetime::text, building::text';  
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
    SELECT 
    student,
    professor_name,
    subject,
    room_number,
    ' || _columns || '
    FROM "school_records_table"  '
   USING  _columns;
END
$func$;
```

I have been receiving an error when I try this

```
SELECT functions.searchandfilter2_function(
    ('students') )
```

Comment: Can you show an error message?

Comment: Try this : `SELECT functions.searchandfilter2_function('students')`

Comment: it says the column does not exist

Comment: RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
    SELECT 
    student,
    professor_name,
    subject,
    room_number,
    $1
    FROM "school_records_table"  '
   USING  _columns;

Comment: The function makes no sense to me. You are using a dynamic list of columns in the SELECT, but your function returns a static list of result columns. So why the dynamic SQL at all? But you can't pass column names with the `USING` clause - that's only used for passing _values_ (not identifiers)

Comment: Most probably not the reason for the error, but functions that return a table, should be put into the from clause: `select * from functions.searchandfilter2_function(...)`

Comment: thank you for this! needed someone to explain what's going on with the this is just my first time trying to create one

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how can I pass column names?

Comment: @driedbananas: You can't. Only in dynamic SQL. To get started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18386034/939860 Remember to disclose your Postgres version and the verbatim error message in your next question.