# SQL - omit repeating the table name

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, dry

Let's say I want to create a new table from an existing table in SQL (postgres). I want the new table to have the same name as the old table but I want it to be in a different schema.

Is there a way to do this without having to repeat the name of the two tables (who share one name?)

Let's say the name of the original table is public.student

```
CREATE TABLE student(
    student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    last_name VARCHAR(30),
    major VARCHAR(30))
```

Now I want to have the exact table but I want it to be in test.student
I know I would "clone" that table via

```
CREATE TABLE test.student AS 
SELECT * 
FROM public.student;
```

but I would like to write this without having to repeat writing "student".
Is there a way to write a function for this?

I'm quite new to SQL, so I'm thankful for any help! I looked into functions and I wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: There is not. Otherwise the database would have no idea what table is being used to create the other.

Comment: Define "repeat". You mean, you want to type it only *once*? And always your version of Postgres.

Comment: yes, I only want to write "student" once (the name is a lot more complex in reality). I use the latest version which is 14.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a [procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) (or a function) with dynamic SQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE foo(_schema text, _table text)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %1$I.%2$I AS TABLE public.%2$I'
                , _schema, _table);
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
CALL foo('test', 'student');
```

Note that input strings for identifiers are case sensitive in this context!

Be wary of possible SQL injection. `format()` with the format specifier `%I` (for *identifier*) is safe. Nested `1$` and `2$` in  `%1$I` and `%2$I` are ordinal references to `format()` arguments.

See:

- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)