# Select concatenated columns based on criteria list in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, concatenation, dynamic-sql

I have a table1

| line | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | 2 | 2 | 22 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 20 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 10 | 2 | 2 | 222 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 12 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 15 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

And a table2

| line | criteria |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a,b |
| 2 | b,c,f,h |
| 3 | a,b,e,g,h |
| 4 | c,e |

I am using this code to see/select the unique results of concated/joined columns, like `concat(c,',',d)`, `concat(b,',',d,',',g)` and so on from `table1` and is working perfectly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(c,',',d)) 
FROM table1
```

But, instead of writing manually like `concat(c,',',d)`, I want to refer to `table2.criteria` to get columns references to be concated/joined from `table1` so that i can see the entire unique results against each concated criteria

Tried this, but getting an [error:](https://dbfiddle.uk/WMRrAoyc)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SELECT criteria FROM table2) 
FROM table1
```

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> SQL state: 21000

The expected unique result is something like this;

```
| criteria     | result     |
| ------------ | ---------- |
| a,b          | 15,2       |
| a,b          | 10,2       |
| a,b          | 20,2       |
| a,b          | 12,2       |
| a,b          | 18,2       |
| b,c,f,h      | 2,2,2,2    |
| b,c,f,h      | 2,2,0,2    |
| b,c,f,h      | 2,2,0,0    |
| a,b,e,g,h    | 20,2,0,0,2 |
| a,b,e,g,h    | 12,2,0,0,0 |
| a,b,e,g,h    | 15,2,0,0,0 |
| a,b,e,g,h    | 10,2,0,1,2 |
| a,b,e,g,h    | 18,2,0,1,2 |
| c,e          | 2,0        |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not allow to parameterize identifiers. There are various ways to work around this restriction.

It's unclear from the question, but according to comments you want to concatenate the given pattern for every row in `table1`.

#### 1. Dynamic SQL

Create a helper function (once!) that concatenates and executes statements dynamically.
Basics:

- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_concat_cols(_cols text)
  RETURNS TABLE (result text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
     $q$SELECT concat_ws(',', %s) FROM table1 ORDER BY line$q$, _cols);
END
$func$;
```

It's a set-returning function (a.k.a. "table function"), to return one result row for every row in `table1` for each given pattern.

**Warning:** Converting user input to code like this is a prime opportunity for **SQL injection**. You must make sure that `table1.criteria` can only hold valid strings!

To get the full result matrix (with distinct results per row in table2), the query is simple now:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT line AS t2_line, criteria, t1.*
FROM   table2, f_concat_cols(criteria) t1
ORDER  BY t2_line;
```

#### 2. Workaround with conversion to JSON

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t2.line AS t2_line, t2.criteria, c.*
FROM   table2 t2
CROSS  JOIN (SELECT line, to_json(t) AS js FROM table1 t) t1
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(t1.js->>sub, ',') AS result
   FROM   string_to_table(t2.criteria, ',') sub
   ) c
ORDER  BY t2_line;
```

After converting rows from `t1` to a JSON record, we can access keys (converted from column names) directly.
I unnest the pattern with [`string_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.35.1.1.1) (Postgres 14+), access each single key, and aggregate the result in a `LATERAL` subquery. See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

You could encapsulate the logic in a function like in ***1.***, but that's optional in this case.

#### 3. Workaround with conversion to Postgres arrays

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t2.line AS t2_line, t2.criteria, c.*
FROM   table2 t2
CROSS  JOIN (SELECT line, ARRAY [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h] AS arr FROM table1 t) t1
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(t1.arr[idx::int]::text, ',') AS result
   FROM   string_to_table(translate(t2.criteria, 'abcdefgh', '12345678'), ',') idx
   ) c
ORDER  BY t2_line;
```

Similar to the "trick" with JSON, we can avoid dynamic SQL by converting columns to a plain Postgres array. Then project column names to integer array indices. I use `translate()` for the simple case, but that only works for single letters! Use `replace()` or `regexp_replace()` or some other method for longer names.
The rest is like the above.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IhqT9T-c) - showing all.

Comment: Can you please check the following link [https://dbfiddle.uk/huOOMD8G], the output is only based on 1st row, but i need summery of entire table. thanks

Comment: @Gulya: I factored in the line number, too, now.

Comment: @ Erwin Brandstetter still the total output is only 4 lines, the result of "a,b" itself should be 5 lines like ("18,2", "20,2", "10,2", "12,2", and "15,2")

Comment: @Gulya Can you put that requirement into the question? And explain why you added `DISTINCT`. I added some more solutions above.

Comment: @  Erwin I have amended the question, so can you please check it. thanks

Comment: Integrated DISTINCT.