# Syntax error at or near ""20231002"" in procedure with dynamic table name

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, procedure, dynamic-sql, identifier

I want to create procedure which can create a table with dynamic table name. It takes a date, formats and appends it to the table name.

What I did:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE l2.accounts_balances_load(var_balancedate date)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
declare var_balancedate_ int = to_char(var_balancedate, 'YYYYMMDD') ;  
begin

raise notice 'SQL:: %', var_balancedate_;

execute format ('create table if not exists l2.accounts_balances_%I partition of l2.accounts_balances', var_balancedate_);

end;
$procedure$
;
```

I call with:

```
call l2.accounts_balances_load('2023-10-02');
```

But I get error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near ""20231002""
Где: PL/pgSQL function l2.accounts_balances_load(date) line 9 at EXECUTE
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need the format specifier [`%s` instead of `%I` for `format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) in this case. Like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE l2.accounts_balances_load(var_balancedate date)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
DECLARE
   var_balancedate_ text := to_char(var_balancedate, 'YYYYMMDD');
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE 'SQL:: %', var_balancedate_;

   EXECUTE format(
      'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS l2.accounts_balances_%s
       PARTITION OF l2.accounts_balances', var_balancedate_);
END
$proc$;
```

Also, no point in coercing the formatted date in `var_balancedate_` to `int` and back. I made it `text`.

The specifier `%I` treats the input as identifier and double-quotes the string if it wouldn't be valid otherwise. A string of digits gets double-quoted. The *subsequent* concatenation makes an illegal name.

Now, your table name *is* an identifier, but you are only appending the number. You would have to double-quote the whole name. Since `var_balancedate_` is assigned the result of `to_char()`, we know the string is safe, so no SQL injection possible, and `%s` is fine.
Else you would concatenate the whole table name, and pass it in with the `%I` specifier to be quoted as a whole.

Related:

- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)