How to use parametrized query with variable in PL/pgSQL?
DO 
$$ 
DECLARE lang TEXT;
    myvar dictionary_keys_view.it%TYPE;
begin 
     lang = 'it';
  SELECT INTO myvar lang FROM dictionary_keys_view WHERE key = 'ENDED';
   raise notice 'title id: %', myvar;
end;
$$;

When i execute this in pgAdmin I receive:

NOTICE:  title id: it
DO
Query returned successfully in 101 msec."


Where's the error?
I tried to declare in different ways the lang var but I never used PL/pgSQL.

What are you trying to do? 1) This myvar dictionary_keys_view.it%TYPE; is declaring a variable of the data type corresponding to myvar dictionary_keys_view.it. 2) This lang = 'it'; needs to happen in the DECLARE section.  3) You need to spend some time here plpgsql in particular sections 43.2. and 43.3.

I believe you are looking for: SELECT INTO myvar it FROM dictionary_keys_view WHERE key = 'ENDED';. Get rid of the lang = 'it';. If you did lang = 'it' to get a dynamic field name you need to read this Dynamic SQL for the proper way of doing that.

With more coffee I realized 2) in my first comment was wrong. I missed the lang TEXT on the DECLARE line, so lang='it' is correct.

basically I need a subquey like this:
SELECT it FROM dictionary_keys_view WHERE key = 'CREATED'
dictionary_keys_view containing coded values with translated it and en. I would select the column it or en based on user language so i have to parametrized this var passing it from java during the invoke of the function

See answer from @Erwin Brandstetter. You are trying to select a column name  and that is an identifier not a data value. To make this work you will need to use the techniques shown here Dynamic SQL, one of which is shown in the answer.

Assuming you want to parameterize a column name. You need dynamic SQL with EXECUTE for that:
DO
$do$ 
DECLARE
   _lang text := 'it';
   _myvar dictionary_keys_view.it%TYPE;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format($q$SELECT %I FROM dictionary_keys_view WHERE key = 'ENDED'$q$, _lang)
   INTO    _myvar;

   RAISE NOTICE 'title id: %', _myvar;
END
$do$;

The filter WHERE key = 'ENDED' should produce a single result row, or there are more issues.
I am not convinced you need the dynamic type declaration with dictionary_keys_view.it%TYPE. Should be a string type? Then just use type text.
Maybe you can just use plain SQL instead.
Related:

PostgreSQL function taking column name as argument
Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter
Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?


thanks the solution worked! Just another question: if i have to parametrized more than one column which letters i must use (%I, %L,)?

@thulandar: %I is a format specifier for the function format(), used for identifiers. Details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18386034/939860
