# type EXECUTE does not exist in postgresql query

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create following function. Function has been created successfully but when trying to call it's throwing error

> type EXECUTE does not exist!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exa(ids text, length integer, fields text)  returns text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    chars INT[] := string_to_array(ids, ',');
    result text := '';
    i integer := 0;
    temp text := '';
BEGIN

    for i in 1..length loop
        temp := EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || fields || ' from user_index where userid=' || chars[i];
            result := result || temp;
        IF i < length THEN
            result := result || ',';    
        END IF;
    end loop;
    return result;
END
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Try EXEC instead of EXECUTE

Comment: @phpdeveloperbalaji no luck

Comment: @phpdeveloperbalaji: "EXEC" is just nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `fields` is supposed to be a column name.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exa(ids text, length integer, fields text
                              ,OUT result text) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _chars INT[] := string_to_array(ids, ',');
    i integer    := 0;
    _temp text   := '';
    _arr  text[];
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..length loop
        EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || fields || ' FROM user_index WHERE userid = chars[i]'
        INTO temp;
        _arr := _arr || temp;
    END LOOP;
    result := array_to_string(result, ',');

    RETURN;
END
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

But ***really*** just:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exa(ids text, fields text, OUT result text) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE
   format($$SELECT string_agg(%I, ',')
            FROM   user_index
            JOIN   unnest(string_to_array($1, ',')::int[]) i(userid)
                                                      USING (userid)$$
         ,fields)
   USING ids
   INTO  result;
END
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT exa('10,11,12', 'kat')
```

And be sure to avoid SQL injection using `format()` with `%I` or some other sane method. Try the search tools. Many similar answers here on SO - like this one (with more explanation and links):
[INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)

Comment: Awesome man! Works like magic. Specially I like the shorter version.

Comment: Don't know why but when I am trying to execute the  alternative version it's throwing following error:

Comment: @ray: I found your error msg. in the rejected edits. I had two errors in the code of the second function. Fixed and tested now.