# Replace delete with trigger function: how to return affected row count?

Tags: postgresql, view, triggers, plpgsql

A standard `delete from foo_history where id = 123;` returns the text:

```
DELETE 1
```

I have created a trigger procedure to replace the delete trigger, and instead of the delete, set an archive flag:

```
CREATE FUNCTION archive()
  RETURNS trigger AS $$
    DECLARE
      command text := '" SET timeEnd = current_timestamp WHERE id = $1';
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE 'UPDATE "' || TG_TABLE_NAME || command USING OLD.id;
      RETURN NULL;
    END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then created a view for the `foo_history` table called `foo`:

```
CREATE VIEW foo AS
SELECT id, timeStart from foo_history WHERE timeEnd IS NULL;
```

And added a trigger to the view:

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo_archive INSTEAD OF DELETE ON foo FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE archive();
```

In other words, when deleting a `foo` record , set the `timeEnd` column instead - this way, the `foo` view only shows records without `timeEnd` set.

This works well:

`delete from foo where id = 123`

Does indeed set the `timeEnd` column. However, the output from this is:

`DELETE 0`

Whereas I really wanted it to say:

`DELETE 1`

Being an SQL novice and Postgres newbie I'm not sure how to change the archive function to do this.

I did try changing it to:

`RETURN 1`

But I get an error about I need to return a composite (whatever that means).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already found that you need to **`RETURN OLD`** in an `INSTEAD OF` trigger for a `DELETE` operation to make the row *count* in the returned *command tag*. The manual:

> A row-level `INSTEAD OF` trigger should either return `NULL` to indicate
>   that it did not modify any data from the view's underlying base
>   tables, or it should return the view row that was passed in (the `NEW`
>   row for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations, or the **`OLD` row for `DELETE`
>   operations**). A nonnull return value is used to signal that the trigger
>   performed the necessary data modifications in the view. **This will
>   cause the count of the number of rows affected by the command to be incremented.**

Bold emphasis mine.

But you also have a sneaky **SQL injection bug** in your current trigger. `TG_TABLE_NAME` is the bare, unquoted name. Identifiers have to be treated as user input - and have to be quoted as necessary in any case. Quote the table name properly in dynamic SQL statements (or you may suffer consequences). One way is to use `format()`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION archive()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I SET time_end = current_timestamp WHERE id = $1', TG_TABLE_NAME)
   USING OLD.id;
   RETURN OLD;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Related:

- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)
- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)

I also used `time_end` instead of `timeEnd`, since my standing advice is to avoid CaMeL case identifiers in Postgres. Related:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: many thanks indeed. I did overlook the entry in the manual for some reason .. and the observation about sql injection was spot on.

Comment: Thank you!! I had tried both `return new` and `return null` but hadn't thought to try `return old`. This got me unstuck.

Answer (score 0):

and, of course, the second I post this, I have an idea which seems to work ..

instead of `RETURN NULL`, use `RETURN OLD`

sorry ...